# MySQL - Rows to Columns Query

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL query question. My current table look like this :

```
  +--------+------+-----+-----+------+
  | hostid | itemname   |  itemvalue |
  +--------+------+-----+-----+------+
  |   A    |      1     |      10    |
  +--------+------+-----+-----+------+
  |   B    |      2     |      3     |
  +--------+------+-----+-----+------+
```

How would I write a query so that I can get an output like this ?

```
  +--------+------+-----+-----+--------+------+-----+----------+
  | itemname_A    | itemvalue_A   |  itemname_B  |  itemvalue_B|
  +--------+------+-----+-----+--------+------+-----+----------+
  |        1      |      10       |       2      |     3       |
  +--------+------+-----+-----+--------+------+-----+----------+
```

Comment: Are no. of `hostid` fixed ? or there can be more

Comment: hostid is fixed

Comment: Although the duplicate is for sql server, the join approach should work on this case

Comment: This question has been asked and answered to soooo many times here on SO.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using some aggregate function you can get the desired output

```
select 
max(case when hostid = 'A' then itemname end) itemname_A,
max(case when hostid = 'A' then itemvalue end) itemvalue_A,
max(case when hostid = 'B' then itemname end) itemname_B,
max(case when hostid = 'B' then itemvalue end) itemvalue_B
from demo
```

> Note it will work for fixed values of hostid 
>   [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f7178f/4)

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much. It may have been a duplicate question, but thanks for taking the time to help with this. really appreciate it!!